# MySql "No route to host" 1% of the time?

Tags: mysql, mono, osx-lion, mysql-connector, ubuntu-11.10

Have a solid application running in Mono on Ubuntu/Apache as well as OSX Lion.

Randomly, I'll get a "no route to host" socket exception - on both Ubuntu and OSX.  Happens to me about 10 times an hour, but not consistently.

I'm using "localhost" - my client and server are running on the same box.  ("localhost" and "127.0.0.1" exhibit the same behavior.)

As a side note: localhost is supposed to use unix sockets, but it isn't.  If I specify "localhost" or "127.0.0.1", I can see traffic on TCP port 3306 for both.  If I use /tmp/mysql.sock as my server, there's obviously no tcp traffic.

This does not happen when I use mysql.sock.

Thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a local loopback adapter set up (no `lo0` interface), and/or you're using external DNS to resolve "localhost". But this is a sysadmin question, not a programming one.

Comment: Thanks.  My hosts file is set up correctly and all other networking is fine.  I suspect it's an issue with the MySql Connector/NET - will ask in the proper place.

Answer (score 0):

It's a late answer, but I do have confidence this was an issue with Mono and Connector/NET.  Using mysql.sock worked flawlessly.  All other code that utilizes sockets works fine.

The same project compiled on Windows in VS.NET also performed without issue.

Finally, this project has since been refactored using Python, and now running for several months without a single hiccup.

So, it's not scientific proof, but all the evidence points to one place.